# How to get the original input using Joi.raw()

Tags: node.js, validation, hapi.js, joi

I'm trying to validate some input with [hapijs/joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#objectassertref-schema-message) and [joi-date-extensions](https://github.com/hapijs/joi-date-extensions)
. I write this code example1.js:

```
const BaseJoi = require('joi');
const Extension = require('joi-date-extensions');
const Joi = BaseJoi.extend(Extension);



const schema = Joi.object().keys({
start_date: Joi.date().format('YYYY-MM-DD').raw(),
end_date: Joi.date().min(Joi.ref('start_date')).format('YYYY-MM-DD').raw(),
});

const obj =  {
start_date: '2018-07-01',
end_date: '2018-06-30',
}

console.log(schema.validate(obj));
```

the code returns this error:

```
child "end_date" fails because ["end_date" must be larger than or equal to "Sun Jul 01 2018 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)"]
```

However I want to get the original input in the error, somthing like that:

```
child "end_date" fails because ["end_date" must be larger than or equal to "2018-07-01"]
```

When I tried this instruction in the example2.js:

```
start_date =  Joi.date().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
console.log(start_date.validate('2018-07-31'));
```

The result was:

```
Tue Jul 31 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

when I use the `raw()` in the example3.js:

```
start_date =  Joi.date().format('YYYY-MM-DD').raw();
console.log(start_date.validate('2018-07-31'));
```

it returns:

```
"2018-07-31"
```

In the example1.js I want to get the original date entred by my code. How  can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.raw` controls how data is transmitted to `Joi.validate`'s callback, i.e. what your data looks like after the validation process. It does *not* control what happens on errors.

To do that, you may want to use [`.error`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v13.6.0/API.md#anyerrorerr). I never used it but I guess it'd be something like this:

```
Joi.date().min(Joi.ref('start_date')).format('YYYY-MM-DD').raw().error(function (errors) {
  var out = [];
  errors.forEach(function (e) {
    out.push(e.message.replace(/".*?"/g, function(match) {
      var dateMatch = Date.parse(match);
      if (isNaN(dateMatch)) {
        return match;
      } else {
        // return formatted date from `dateMatch` here, too lazy to write it in p[l]ain JS...
      }
    }));
  });
  return out;
})
```